# Impact of biased sampling on classifier training ?

Tags: classification, sampling, weighted-sampling, unbalanced-classes

Let's imagine I have a very unbalanced dataset with 99.99% of 0 and 0.01% of 1 on the target variable. What I want to do is make a classifier for this target.

Now imagine that this dataset is very big (billions of rows). Would it be ok to sample say 200.000 individuals 1 and 200.000 individuals 0 ? What would be the impact of doing so versus a random sampling ?

Bonus question :
(More generally what are the techniques to weight more or less observations in order to improve predictions ?)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you measuring performance? Classification accuracy? AUC? Precision/Recall?

Comment: I generally check out a few of them, accuracy, AUC, F1-score ... Why ? Do you know how each of these measures wil be affected ?

Comment: Have you thought of using one-class classification instead of binary classification? Your sample sizes sound as if the problem was particularly ill-posed in a binary classification framework.

Comment: I did not thought about that. If you had some good references to provide that would be helpful. It does not answer the principal question though.